# Can't access dockerized python azure function through api?

Tags: python-3.x, docker, dockerfile, azure-functions, azure-functions-core-tools

I'm trying access HTTP trigger python function that's running inside Azure container.
I've followed the below url

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-function-linux-custom-image

When I'm testing my azure function in python, I'm getting HTTP ERROR 401.
How to resolve it and the following is my docker run command

```
docker run -p 8000:80 -it <dockerid>/mydockerimage:v1.0.0
```

Comment: A 401 is an unauthorized error. I suggest double checking how you are authenticating and authorizing to Azure.

Comment: I didn't do anything for authentication, I have just followed the documentation, what do I need to do?

Comment: IDK, I've found that Azure's docs can be a little lacking. You're replacing `<dockerid>` with your actual docker ID right?

Answer (score 0):

There's not enough information here to help you; however, you need to make sure that if you've set `AuthorizationLevel.Function`, such as in here:

`[HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,`

...you need to ensure that you are including `x-functions-key` header in your request, or you can get the URL of the function:

[image]

The URL will have the `code` appended to it.

Comment: Get Function URL is not available in azure function running on docker image in linux environment

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow anonymous access to a Python Azure Function, you can set it in the **function.json** file in the folder of that function.

E.g. see the ***"authLevel": "anonymous"*** value in this sample:

(the default value is "authLevel": "function")

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "$return"
    }
  ]
}
```